# Como exportar e importar array de objetos em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, importação

Estou criando um sistema, e dentro dos códigos principais tenho grandes arrays de objetos que armazenam informações sobre produtos e informações nas quais utilizo dentro das funções para certas operações do sistema.

Porém armazenar as informações dos produtos na página dos códigos principais está me atrapalhando muito e eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma maneira de importar esses arrays de objetos de uma página a outra sem comprometer as funcionalidades das funções que utilizam como parâmetro algumas informações dos produtos.

Exemplo de código:

```
const produtos = [
    {nome: "notebook", custo: 1.500},
    {nome: "cama", custo: 2000},
    {nome: "ventilador", custo: 200}
]

function getNames(){

    produtos.map((produto) => {
        return produto.nome
    })
}
```

Neste exemplo, eu gostaria de colocar o array de objetos em outra página, para fazer uma importação sem comprometer a função `getNames()`. Seria isso possível?

Comment: Talvez carregar de um arquivo JSON usando axios?

Comment: e como eu faria isso?

Comment: você está usando apenas o vanilla javascript (javascript de html)?

Comment: estou usando NODE JS e React JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma mais fácil de fazer importação no Node é utilizando a função `require(path)`, exportando o objeto através do atributo `module.exports`, dessa seguinte forma:

**Arquivo que exporta:**

```
// Atribui a module.exports o objeto para ser exportado

const produtos = [
    {nome: "notebook", custo: 1.500},
    {nome: "cama", custo: 2000},
    {nome: "ventilador", custo: 200}
]

module.exports = produtos;

// Você também pode importar vários objetos colocando-os dentro de um objeto.
// Exemplo: module.exports = {produtos: produtos, registro: "2020-03-12", code: 3714};
```

**Arquivo que importa:**

```
const produtos = require("./path/arquivo_que_exporta");
```

---

Uma coisa bem interessante, é que o script inteiro é executado antes do objeto ser exportado. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
module.exports = [1, 2, 3];

// Essa mensagem será impressa antes do objeto ser exportado no outro arquivo.
console.log("Continua a execução...");
```

Comment: e como eu faria pra exportar mais de um array de objetos ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Você deve colocar os objetos dentro de um objeto. Editei a resposta para você entender melhor.

Answer (score 3):

Apenas exporte a function

o arquivo onde está localizado a função

```js
export const getNames = () => produtos.map(({ name }) => name)
```

o arquivo onde você quer usar a função

```js
import { getNames } from './path/to/file'
```

Espero que tenha ajudado

Comment: vish vey, tentei e deu o seguinte erro:  Parsing error: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level